# How do I delete a white layer over dialog background in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

I am trying to do a transparent background for my MatDialog component. Here is the code:

*parent.component.html*

```
openDialog(){

  const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

  dialogConfig.width = '340px';
  dialogConfig.height = '476px';
  dialogConfig.panelClass = "dialogClass";

  this.dialog.open(ChildComponent, dialogConfig)
}
```

*styles.css (global file, not the parent component one)*

```
.dialogClass{
    background-color: pink;  //pink to see if it works
}
```

*(changes background for this particular dialog)*

**OR**

```
mat-dialog-container {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

*(changes background for all dialogs)*

This code works (I can see pink for a second every time I open the dialog), but it gets instantly covered with a white layer. All I have in my ChildComponent is displayed *over* this layer:

**MatDialog background -> White layer -> ChildComponent**

If ChildComponent *.css* and *.html* files are empty, it still appears.
Setting a block with transparent background doesn't help either.

How do I delete this white layer from a dialog?

Answer (score 0):

This should work ; write this code inside style.scss (global scss file).This will make the dialog background transparent.

```
.DialogClass .mat-dialog-container {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. This approach is similar to the 2nd one I describe, but for the single component only. The white layer still overlaps it.

Comment: I am sharing a stackblitz link with you please click on the open confirm dialog button and take a look at the output and it would be great if you can confirm if that's the desired output you want.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-u8sy9k?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,styles.scss,app%2Fconfirmation-dialog.component.ts